# Simpler proof that $\det A\neq 0$ if $A$ is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, proof-writing

One excercise asked me to **"Prove that the determinant of an inversible matrix can't be 0"**. I couldn't remember the proof the teacher gave and I didn't want to "cheat" because I'm practising for an exam, so after some thinking I came up with this.

I'd like to know **if someone has a simpler and/or shorter proof** than mine, and **if someone can find any mistakes** in my proof. Oh, and if someone can **suggest a way to shorten it** or maybe use more symbols and less natural language.

I lost the sheet of the proof the teacher provided, and Googling/searching books I found nothing (only proof that $\det{(A ^{-1})} = 1/\det A$). Maybe I didn't word it properly because English is not my native language.

### Proof

First, proof that the determinant of an elementary matrix $[E]$ can't be 0:

An elementary matrix $[E]$ is defined as a matrix obtained by applying a single row operation to the identity matrix. $|I|=1$, so:

$|E|=1$ if it comes from adding a row to another one
$|E|=-1$ if it comes from swapping two rows
$|E|=k/k\in\Bbb R \land k≠0$ if it comes from multiplying a row by $k$

$|E|≠0$

Now, let's say we have a square matrix $[A]_{n\times n}$ that is invertible. To obtain the inverse of $[A]$ we have to apply row operations to the augmented matrix $[A|I]$ until we get $[I|A^{-1}]$. Let's say $E_1*E_2*...E_n$ are the elementary matrixes we premultiply our initial augmented matrix by to get the identity and the inverse. Then we get:

$$E_1*E_2*...E_n * A = I$$ and $$E_1*E_2*...E_n * I = A^{-1}$$

Let's take the first one, and apply determinant to both sides of the equality

$$|E_1*E_2*...E_n * A| = |I|$$
$$|E_1*E_2*...E_n|*|A| = 1$$

Now let's **suppose** $|A|$ *could* be $0$. We would get:

$$|E_1*E_2*...E_n|*0 = 1$$
$$0 = 1$$

Which is absurd, and thus **the determinant of an invertible matrix can't be 0**.

Comment: The idea is fine the way it is, but since you seem to already now that the determinant is multiplicative you can vastly shorten the proof. If $A$ has an inverse $B$, then $\det(A) \det(B) = \det(AB) = \det(I) = 1$, and if $\det(A) = 0$ we have a problem.

Comment: This is fine, but you don't need the unnecessary proof by contradiction. Just use your equation to deduce directly that $|A|\ne 0$.

Answer (score 4):

Our OP El Menduko's proof looks fine to me.

As per his (I assume the masculine is *apropos* here, based on the appearance of "El" in the OP's user name.) request, here is a shorter proof, as indicated in the comments:

If $A$ is invertible, there is a matrix $B$ with

$AB = I; \tag 1$

then

$\vert AB \vert = \vert I \vert = 1; \tag 2$

but

$\vert AB \vert = \vert A \vert \vert B \vert; \tag 3$

thus

$\vert A \vert \vert B \vert = I, \tag 4$

which of course prohibits $\vert A \vert = 0$; we are left with the sole option

$\vert A \vert \ne 0. \tag 5$

***Note:***  I had just composed and begun to type this answer when the comment of user 296602 appeared.  I guess that person deserves some credit as well, so I tip my hat.  I prefer to answer some of these questions to help cut down on the number of questions without answers, even if they do have the equivalent in the comments.  ***End of Note.***

Comment: (+1), and I certainly don't mind. It's a nice answer.

Comment: @user296602:  Thank you my friend.  It's hard not to duplicate your words, word-for-word, when the logic is so simple.  Cheers!

Comment: I see. I really am an overthinker. Thank you and everyone who answered

Answer (score 2):

Recall
$$ det(AB) = det(A)det(B) $$
$$ AA^{-1}=I \iff \text{ $A$ is invertible.} $$
Suppose $A$ is an invertible matrix. Note that if $A$ is invertible, then it follows that $A \neq 0$. So
$$ det(A)det(A^{-1}) = 1. $$
Suppose $ det(A) = 0 $. Then
$$ 0 = 1 $$
Which is a contradiction. Then $det(A) \neq 0$.